# Group html table rows with HXT in Haskell

Tags: haskell, html-table, hxt

I want to process a (very poorly defined) html, which has the information grouped in pairs of rows, like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>
         <font >
         <a href="a">ABC</a></font>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td height="50">
         <font>When:</font><font>19-1-2013</font>
          <b><font>&nbsp; </font></b>
         <font>Where:</font><font>Here</font>
         <font>Who:</font><font>Me</font>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
        <font >
             <a href="b">EFG</a>
        </font>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td height="50">
         <font>When:</font><font>19-2-2013</font>
         <b><font>&nbsp; </font></b>
         <font>Where:</font><font>There</font>
         <font>Who:</font><font>You</font>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
        <font >
            <a href="c">HIJ</a>
        </font>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td height="50">
         <font>When:</font><font>19-3-2013</font><b>
         <font>&nbsp; </font></b>
         <font>Where:</font><font>Far away</font>
         <font>Who:</font><font>Him</font>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

To this, after several iterations, I arrived at this code to achieve what I want:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow.ArrowNavigatableTree
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.HandsomeSoup

group2 [] = []
group2 (x0:x1:xs) = [x0,x1]:(group2 xs)

countRows html = html >>> deep (hasName "tr") >. length

parsePage sz html = let
  n x = deep (hasName "tr") >. (( -> a !! x) . group2 ) >>> unlistA
  m = deep (hasName "td") >>> css "a" /> getText
  o = deep (hasName "td") >>> hasAttr "height" >>> (css "font" >. (take 1 . drop 4)) >>> unlistA /> getText
  p x = (((n x) >>> m) &&& ((n x) >>> o))
  in html >>> catA [p x | x <- [0..sz]]

main = do
    dt <- readFile "test.html"
    let html = parseHtml dt
    count <- (runX . countRows) html
    let cnt = ((head count) `div` 2) - 1
    prcssd <- (runX . (parsePage cnt)) html
    print prcssd
```

And the result is:
    [("ABC","Here"),("EFG","There"),("HIJ","Far away")]

However, I don't think this is a very good aproach, having to count the rows first. Is there a better way of doing this grouping using HXT? I've tried the &&& operator with little luck.

The question at [extract multiples html tables with hxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911918/extract-multiples-html-tables-with-hxt), while useful, presents a simpler situation, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a somewhat simpler implementation.

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.HandsomeSoup

group2 :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
group2 [] = []
group2 (x0:x1:xs) = (x0, x1) : group2 xs

parsePage :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree (String, String)
parsePage = let
    trPairs    = deep (hasName "tr") >>. group2
    insideLink = deep (hasName "a") /> getText
    insideFont = deep (hasName "font") >>. (take 1 . drop 4) /> getText

    in trPairs >>> (insideLink *** insideFont)


main = do
    dt <- readFile "test.html"
    let html = parseHtml dt
    prcssd <- runX $ html >>> parsePage
    print prcssd
```

The [`>>.`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v%3a-62--62--46-) operator can be used instead of `>.` so that you don't need to call `unlistA` afterwards.

I changed the `group2` function to return a list of pairs, because it maps better with what we are trying to achieve and it's easier to work with.

The type of `trPairs` is

```
trPairs :: ArrowXml a => a XmlNode (XmlNode, XmlNode)
```

i.e. it's an arrow that takes in nodes and outputs a pair of nodes (i.e. the paired up `<tr>` nodes). Now we can use the [`***`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v%3a-42--42--42-) operator from [`Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html) to apply a transformation to either element of the pair, `insideLink` for the first one and `insideFont` for the second one. This way we can collect and group everything we need with a single traversal of the HTML tree.

Comment: That's precisely it. I already got into grouping them in pairs, but it did not occurr to me that a tupple is the most appropriate solution, hence allowing me to use (***). Thanks! I then also wanted to grab more than one field from the 'properties' rows, and thus I just had to modify your function: `insideFont = (deep (hasName "font") >>. (\x → [x !! 1]) /> getText ) &&& (deep (hasName "font") >>. (\x → [x !! 4]) /> getText )` . This wasn't in the question, of course, I just included it in the case someone else might find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

I did some html parsing with hxt a few weeks ago and thought, that [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) comes in quite handy. Unfortunately, I didn't come up with a perfect solution for your problem, but it might be a start for a new try.

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.XML.HXT.XPath.Arrows

type XmlTreeValue a = a XmlTree String
type ParsedXmlTree a = a XmlTree XmlTree
type IOXmlTree = IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree

-- parses a given .html file
parseHtml :: FilePath -> IOStateArrow s b XmlTree
parseHtml path = readDocument [withParseHTML yes, withWarnings no] path

-- "" for stdout
saveHtml :: IOXmlTree
saveHtml = writeDocument [withIndent yes] ""

extract :: IOXmlTree
extract = processChildren (process `when` isElem)

-- main processing functon
processHtml :: FilePath -> IO ()
processHtml src =
  runX (parseHtml src >>> extract >>> saveHtml)
   >> return ()

-- process the html structure
process :: ArrowXml cat => ParsedXmlTree cat
process =
  -- create tag <structure> for the expression given next
  selem "structure"
    -- navigate to <html><body><table><tr>...
    [(getXPathTrees "/html/body/table/tr")
      -- then combine the results
      >>> (getTheName <+> getWhere)]

 -- selects text at path <td><font><a...> </a></font></td> and creates <name>-Tag
 -- (// means that all <td>-tags are analysed,
 --  but I'm not quite sure why this is relevant here)
 getTheName :: ArrowXml cat => ParsedXmlTree cat
 getTheName = selem "name" [getXPathTrees "//td/font/a/text()"]

 -- selects text at path <td><font><a...> </a></font></td>
 -- (where the forth font-tag is taken) and creates <where>-Tag
 getWhere  :: ArrowXml cat => ParsedXmlTree cat
 getWhere = selem "where" [getXPathTrees "//td/font[4]/text()"]
```

The result looks like this:

```
*Main> processHtml "test.html"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<structure>
 <name>ABC</name>
 <where/>
 <name/>
 <where>Here</where>
 <name>EFG</name>
 <where/>
 <name/>
 <where>There</where>
 <name>HIJ</name>
 <where/>
 <name/>
 <where>Far away</where>
</structure>
```

Like I said, not quite perfect, but hopefully a start.

EDIT:
Maybe this looks more like your approach. Still, instead of dropping the elements you don't care about, we first choose all elements that fit and filter the results. I think it's quite fascinating that there's no generic approach for such a problem. Because, somehow, the font[4]-selection does not work with my other approach - but maybe I'm just not a good xpath user.

```
processHtml :: FilePath -> IO [(String,String)]
processHtml src = do
  names <- runX (parseHtml src >>> process1)
  fontTags <- runX (parseHtml src >>> process2)
  let wheres = filterAfterWhere fontTags
  let result = zip names wheres
  return result
 where filterAfterWhere [] = []
       filterAfterWhere xs = case dropWhile (/= "Where:") xs of
                               []     -> []
                               [x]    -> [x]
                               _:y:ys -> y : filterAfterWhere ys

process1 :: ArrowXml cat => XmlTreeValue cat
process1 = textNodeToText getTheName

process2 :: ArrowXml cat => XmlTreeValue cat
process2 =  textNodeToText getWhere

getTheName :: ArrowXml cat => ParsedXmlTree cat
getTheName = getXPathTrees "//td/font/a/text()"

getWhere  :: ArrowXml cat => ParsedXmlTree cat
getWhere = getXPathTrees "//td/font/text()"

-- neet function to select a value within a XmlTree as String
textNodeToText :: ArrowXml cat => ParsedXmlTree cat -> XmlTreeValue cat
textNodeToText selector = selector `when` isElem >>> getText
```

This way, you get the result you showed in your question:

```
*Main> processHtml "test.html"
[("ABC","Here"),("EFG","There"),("HIJ","Far away")]
```

Edit2:

Fun fact: it seems like the hxt-xpath library does not work quite right for such an index-selection. [An online XPath-evaluator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) shows the right behaviour for `//td/font[4]/text()`.

Comment: I actually did not know the XPath extensions, tks! I seemed to have no problem with using the [] predicate... even the position() one is supported. What is not supported is the "following" and "preceding" axes, which would be quite useful. I had also tried using CSS2 selectors on the Text.HandsomeSoup package for a similar effect, but they are mostly not implemented. Your second solution, while correct, is not quite what I wanted: it implies a double transversal of the HTML tree, as @shang noticed,a solution I personally prefer. I still upvoted you since your solution is more elegant than mine